# What happens to a DOM element created as part of an IIFE

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's say I execute a function in the following way:

```
function el(html) {
  return (function(parent){
    parent.innerHTML = html;

    return parent.childNodes[0];
  })(document.createElement('div'));
};

document.body.appendChild(el('<p>foo</p>'));
document.body.appendChild(el('<p>bar</p>'));
```

What happens to the element that was created (with the tag div as a parameter go the IIFE)?
If I execute the function n times will I be left with n orphan DOM nodes?

Comment: When you execute a function, it doesn't matter if it's a named function that's called from elsewhere, or an IIFE. The effects on the DOM are the same.

Comment: What is purpose of creating `temp` element?

Comment: @guest271314 updated question for clarity

Comment: @Lewis `javascript` is same as before update. The created node does not appear to be appended to `document`, nor referenced outside of IIFE, not certain what you mean by "orphan DOM nodes"?

Comment: There's also no reason to use an IIFE in this context.  Just make `el()` a normal function with it's own local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the objects are not reachable from GC roots then they are eligible for garbage collection. This also applies to DOM nodes.

Side note: [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) or [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) would be more idiomatic approaches to build and append html from strings

Comment: That's what I was hoping for ... but my confusion is this: the return value is a node, which has a reference to the parent. So surely the node won't be eligible for GC until the until the outer scope is eligible?

Comment: `appendChild` also changes the parent, thus making the old parent unreachable